# Quickly browse throw types implementing or declaring a method

Tags: java, eclipse

The Eclipse IDE allows to quickly browse through the results of a search by using Show next match / Show previous match in the Search view.

Selecting Quick Hierarchy with Ctrl+T for a method shows all types that implementing or declaring it.

Is there a way to browse through the types offered by Ctrl+T as conveniently as one can through search results?  Currently, it seems you have to open the types one by one and then redo the Ctrl+T action.

Comment: Is the _Type Hierarchy_ (F4) view with _Lock View and Show Members in Hierarchy_ what you're looking for?

Comment: Certainly an improvement. But not fully there: this view is based on the type, not on the method. Means, you have to click on the type and then on your method again to see the implementation. Plus: if a class does not implement the method itself but uses the one of its super, it is still appears in the list.

Comment: If [_Lock View and Show Members in Hierarchy_](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/ref-type-hierarchy.htm) is enabled, an additional subnode for the method is added to each type node and subtypes that do not override this method are excluded. You do not have to click on the type nodes, you can directly click on the method nodes.

Comment: You are right. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ***Type Hierarchy*** (<kbd>F4</kbd>) view with the option ***Lock View and Show Members in Hierarchy*** for that. The option adds a method subnode to each type node and hides subtypes that do not override the method.

Example [`remove(int) - java.util.AbstractList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#remove-int-):

[image]